# How do I check if a table have matching record in another table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following tables:

**Table 1 : `AccessMenu`**

```
userid  item

1        a 

2        b    

2        c
```

and

**Table 2  : `ActionRights`**

```
idAdmin   itemCol

2          v

2          m

2          d
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
  userid      yes/no

   1           no

   2           yes
```

When I get matching `userid` to `idadmin` in `ActionRight` it should return `Yes` otherwise `No`.

I tried below query:

```
select AccessMenu.userid,
case when ActionRights.IdAdmin=AccessMenu.userid then 'Yes' else 'No' end as 'GRP'
from AccessMenu left join ActionRights
on ActionRights.IdAdmin =AccessMenu.userid
```

But through this query i am getting repeated result as:

```
 userid      yes/no

   1           no

   2           yes

   2           yes

   2           yes

   2           yes

   2           yes
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, 
       CASE 
         WHEN idadmin IS NULL THEN 'No' 
         ELSE 'Yes' 
       END AS 'Grp' 
FROM   (SELECT accessmenu.userid    AS UserId, 
               actionrights.idadmin AS IdAdmin 
        FROM   accessmenu 
               LEFT JOIN actionrights 
                      ON actionrights.idadmin = accessmenu.userid)z
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check using subquery:

```
select distinct
    userid, 
    case when (SELECT COUNT(*) from ActionRights b where b.idAdmin=a.userid)>0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end [Yes/No]
from AccessMenu a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct  UserId, CASE WHEN  IsAdmin  IS  NULL  THEN  'No'  ELSE  'Yes' END AS 'Grp'
FROM (  
      select AccessMenu.userid as UserId ,ActionRights.IsAdmin as IsAdmin
      from AccessMenu left join ActionRights
      on ActionRights.IsAdmin =AccessMenu.userid
     )a
```

Have a look

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07d52/10

Answer (score 1):

> Its simple. No need of Inner queries or Subqueries. Just take the
>   Distinct

```
 SELECT DISTINCT AM.USERID,
 CASE WHEN AR.USERID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS [YES/NO] 
 FROM #ACCESSMENU AM
 LEFT JOIN #ACCESSRIGHT AR ON AM.USERID=AR.USERID
```